# Browsing random page of a particular website

Tags: gratis, web

I am searching for a free online site or a free tool (Windows or Mac OS) that can let me browse random pages (one at a time) of a specified website (that I specify) but I didn't find any.

Do you know any such site or tool?

Comment: For a tool, please specify operating system(s).  Also please specify if you are looking for recommendations for gratis tools or paid tools.

Comment: I am looking for windows OS and free tool

Comment: You want the app to give you a link to the page which you can open in the browser?

Comment: Yes an app or an online site.